# What is a good way to call a function that makes an axios request using information from within a v-for?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I am working on an e-commerce site using rails and VueJS. I have a component file to display the orders of a given user. I am using a v-for loop to iterate and display all the user's order info. each order is linked to a carted products table where the product I.D. is located. I want to display the product information of each product within each order. I have a productShow function that makes an axios request to the backend and retrieves the product's info, the problem is I'm not sure how to capture the product ID from each of the products in the carted product array to send with the request. Even if I manage that how would I display each product within each order and the order's info as well? I have been unsuccessful in my attempts thus far and am looking for some guidance. code and info below.

ordersIndex.Vue component:

```
  <div class="home">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div  v-for="order in orders">
      <h2>Order Number:{{ order.id }}</h2>
      <h1 v-for="cartedProduct in order.carted_products"> <strong>{{ cartedProduct }}</strong> </h1>

      <h3>SUBTOTAL:{{ order.subtotal }}</h3>
      <h3>TAX:{{ order.tax }}</h3>
      <h3>TOTAL: {{ order.total }}</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
</style>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: "Your Orders",
      orders: [],
      anOrder: [],
      cartedProducts: [],
      product: {},
      productId: "",
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log("In Created...");
    this.orderIndex();
    // this.cartedProductsonOrder();
  },

  methods: {
    orderIndex: function () {
      console.log("In orderIndex...");
      axios.get("/api/orders").then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.orders = response.data;
        this.cartedProductsonOrder();
      });
    },
    productShow: function (id) {
      console.log("in products show");
      axios.get("/api/products/" + id).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.product = response.data;
        console.log("Line 53");
        console.log(this.product);
        this.cartedProducts.push(this.product);
        console.log(this.cartedProducts);
      });
    },
    cartedProductsonOrder: function () {
      console.log("In cartedProductsonOrder method....");
      console.log(this.orders);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
        console.log("Line 62");
        console.log(this.orders[i].carted_products);
        this.cartedProducts = this.orders[i].carted_products;

        for (let j = 0; j < this.cartedProducts.length; j++) {
          console.log("Line 67");
          console.log(this.cartedProducts[j]);
          console.log(this.cartedProducts[j].product_id);
          this.productId = this.cartedProducts[j].product_id;
          this.productShow(this.productId);
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Screenshots of console log:

[order response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld2ln.png)

[carted products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC5cJ.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code as code blocks in the question instead of images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6294072

Comment: When you are using a v-for in a v-for try to create a separate component for readability.

Comment: You might want to consider creating a separate order detail view to show the list of carted products associated with a given order.  Then in your order list, create a link on each order to take you to that order's detail view.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: you seem to have everything, except for each `cartedProduct` (which contains the `product_id`), you have to fetch the product-information, right? You have a method `cartedProductsonOrder` but it does not seem to do much. Imho you should loop over the cartedProducts and for each fetch the product info and store that instead?

Comment: @RonaldT I appreciate the advice. Thank you!

Comment: @Tim I am considering a modal component to display the products Do you think that would work or would I be facing similar issues?

Comment: @nathanvda I updated the code above and have managed to capture the products in an array except its every product in all the orders, multiples etc. I was wondering if a v-for can except conditionals so I can only display the products that correspond with the order ID.

Comment: @EduardoGutierrez I think a modal would be fine if you understand how to implement one.  The main thing is to get rid of the nested v-for, which is doable but as you are discovering, can be tough to troubleshoot and maintain.  Also having a detail page/modal is a better UI/UX in my opinion.

Comment: @Tim I have implemented modals in another project but never with multiple objects. In any case I think you're right and will go that direction. Thank again! You've been very helpful.

Comment: In all honesty, the best way to do this would be to fetch the items information from the API/backend first, before iterating through them. If you go the modal route, just create a function for the button to open the modal and pass the productId in the function. Then, when you open your modal, execute the request to the API/backend to pull the products information and display it.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested however, it should give you a good idea of how to accomplish what you're after. I have also made a few other changes such as using fat arrow functions and changing to `forEach` loops instead of basic `for` loops.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div v-for="order in orders">
      <h2>Order Number:{{ order.id }}</h2>

      <h1 v-for="product in order.carted_products"> <strong>{{ cartedProduct }}</strong> </h1>

      <h3>SUBTOTAL:{{ order.subtotal }}</h3>
      <h3>TAX:{{ order.tax }}</h3>
      <h3>TOTAL: {{ order.total }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    message: "Your Orders",
    orders: [],
    cartedProducts: []
  }),
  mounted: {
    this.doGetOrders()
  },
  methods: {
    doGetOrders: () => {
      axios.get(`/api/order`).then((response) => {
        this.orders = response.data

        this.doCartedProductsInOrder()
      })
    },
    doCartedProductsInOrder: () => {
      if (this.order.length >= 1) {
        this.order.forEach((order) => {
          if (order.cartedProducts >= 1) {
            order.cartedProducts.forEach((product) => {
              this.cartedProducts.push(this.doGetProductInfo(productId))
            })
          }
        })
      }
    },
    doGetProductInfo: (productId) => {
      axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.data
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```